Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10' or one of its dependencies
I'm on .net 4.8.
After upgrading from 3.1.1 to version 4.0 of Serilog, i get the error:
Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10' or one of its dependencies.
Not sure why it happens this. Maybe a bug?
Did not tried anything else because i don't see any workaround. Just reverted back to version 3.1.1

The problem is because i'm using the Sinks.Seq v.7.0.1 which is the latest version until now, but is referencing the assembly version 2.0.0.0 of Serilog. The file version of Serilog is indead 3.1.1.
When they upgraded(1st of june) the Serilog dll, they finally increased both versions of Serilog Assembly and File to 4.0.0.0.
That broke everything because now i have Sinks.Seq v7.0.1 which references Serilog v3.1.1 with assembly version 2.0.0.0 and Serilog v4.0.0 on the same directory. Of course it is not finding that version.
The solution is to wait until they upgrade the Sinks.Seq with the latest version of Serilog. Until then, nothing can be done except using the version 3.1.1 of Serilog with v 7.0.1
Sinks.Seq v7.0.1

This is what assembly binding redirects are for, did you try that and it not work?
